# Spring 3.1 and Servlet API 3.0. How to use @WebServlet annotation

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

In the [recent Spring 3.1 Release](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/12/13/spring-framework-3-1-goes-ga/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20SpringSourceTeamBlog%20%28SpringSource%20Team%20Blog%29) there is a `@WebServlet` annotation support. But seems that I can not use it. Is there some tutorial for that. This is my Web.xml

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" >
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

... and my beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx" />

    <!-- aop:aspectj-autoproxy aspectj-weaving="on" / -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator" />

    <!-- bean class="xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.MessageProfileLogger" 
        / -->
</beans>
```

The servlet source...

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/service/*" })
public class RequestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    {
        System.out.println("RequestServlet is initialized");
    }
...
}
```

The desired behavior - the annotated servlet is initialized and it starts to listen for requests.

What really happens - nothing, it is like the Servlet is not annotated.

Additional information - the path to the servlet is in the component-scan, other DI stuff also works.

I don't have a enterprise container , I used this tutorial for [Spring+Embeded Jetty](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/42315/1954) which worked till now.

EDIT: Seems that I was using old version of Jetty (7.0.2). Seems that Jetty supports @WebServlet 3.0 since version 8.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I can not use it"? What exactly happens instead?

Comment: @BalusC You are right, I will edit my question.

Comment: Hmm, I don't do Spring, so I'm not sure if that `AbstractServlet` is right, this is in standard Servlet API usually `HttpServlet` (although I believe `AbstractServlet` extends from it under the covers). But are you running a Servlet 3.0 compatible container such as Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc?

Comment: AbstractServlet is subclass of a HttpServlet written by me. It is nothing really special.

Comment: What Jetty version are you using? Only 8 or newer supports Servlet 3.0 API.

Comment: Jetty 7.0.2. Ok, that explains my problem, I will count your last comment as right answer and will upvote one random answer of yours.

Comment: I will just repost it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments:

> Jetty 7.0.2

In order to be able to utilize the Servlet 3.0 API, you need a container which supports the Servlet 3.0 API. That are for example at least Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, WebSphere AS 8, Jetty 8, etc. Changing alone the `web.xml` to comply Servlet 3.0 won't change the container's internal classes to magically support Servlet 3.0 API. Most containers would even fall back to least compatibility modus when an unsupported version is mentioned in `web.xml`.

If you're using embedded Jetty 8, don't forget to add `AnnotationConfiguration` to Jetty config in order to get it to scan for annotations.